# issue with springboot project : org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

hey guys 
 i have a problem in my java spring boot application 
i've built a simple application and connected it with a database 
but when i try to make a POST or GET on the data base my program access the database and do any thing i did but show an error 
**org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "Students", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers**

when i make GET i check the Iterable list and it's already get the data from database 
but doesn't show the data on the localhost 
it's give me that exception 
is there any solution for that ? 
this is my code in controller

```
@Path("Students")
@Controller
public class studentsController {
    @AutoWired
    StudentServices st;
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Iterable<Students> getAllStudents() {
          Iterable<Students> list = st.getAllStudents();
          return list
}
```

Comment: this does not seem to be an issue with database

Comment: no it's not , the issue is in show the data as json

Comment: exactly, which is why you might want to edit the title of the question.

Comment: done , thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @Controller you are defining a Model-View-Controller (MVC) endpoint for returning your view templates. So with `Iterable<Students>` Spring is looking for a `Students` template in your `src/main/resources/templates` folder because it is interpreted as a View name.

If you want to create a REST endpoint which returns a list of Student objects you should use `@RestController` at your class which adds the Spring annotation `@RequestBody` automatically.

Furthermore `@Path("XYZ")` should be replaced with `@RequestMapping("XYZ")` in Spring and `@AutoWired` with `@Autowired`.

An working example could look like the following:

```
@RequestMapping("/students")
@RestController
public class StudentsController {

    @Autowired
    StudentServices st;

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Iterable<Students> getAllStudents() {
          Iterable<Students> list = st.getAllStudents();
          return list
}
```